# Why can't I see how many installs my game has on its Google Play page?

Tags: google-play

I made an Android game, and I uploaded and published it to Google Play. Then, I installed it on my phone.

Why can't I see the install count, on its Google Play page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you just uploaded it today, you won't see the number of installs yet. See [the documentation](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628) where it says the statistics are updated on a daily basis. The statistics are not "live". You'll only be able to see how many people downloaded on a given day *after* the day is over. This is similar to Google Analytics. So be patient and check back later. Congrats on publishing a game.

Answer (score -1):

Google doesn’t release the official downloads/revenue numbers publicly, so it’s impossible to know the exact download numbers for any app—— unless you’re Google, the actual app publisher/developer, or have access to their credentials.

Sensor Tower allows you to see pinpoint download (& revenue) estimates from the previous month for nearly any app in their free platform.
You can access daily and more granular data/figures with their Store Intelligence product, which is used by mobile leaders like Zynga, Uber and Supercell.

Comment: This does not add anything useful to the already accepted answer posted several years ago.

Comment: This looks like an answer to the question "How do I check how many installs *someone else's* game has?" But the question was about seeing installs for one's *own* game.